# How to get the implicit type in an anonymous type?

Tags: c#

I made an anonymous type array. I want to get the implicit type of the "BatchNo" property, which is "string" in red rectangle. In fact, I got the "object" instead. As the red arrow points to.
The minimal reproducible example:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BatchNo", typeof(string)));
table.Rows.Add(new[] { "001" });
var data = table.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>
        new
        {
            BatchNo = r.Field<object>("BatchNo"),
        }
).ToList();
var type = data[0].GetType();
var prop = type.GetProperty("BatchNo");
var propType = prop.PropertyType; //what I want
```

Did I missed something?
[image: GetImplicitTypeInAnonymousType]

the code snippet shows how to get implicit type in an anonymous type property

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you posted the code that created it, a [mre].

Comment: We don't like require readers to solve puzzles - while entertaining in itself ("come up with code that when compiled/executed provides shown error/result" are fun sometimes) it is not fitting the SO goal to be collection of questions (ideally with answer) which can be easily matched to reader's problem. I'd strongly recommend to follow @madreflection advice and [edit] the post with real [mre]. Clearly the most obvious `var data = new[]{new {BatchNo = "a"}};` *does not* exhibit the problem described in the question.

Comment: Note that the only problem I can identify easily is "why `type.GetProperty` is not a type of the property" and I picked duplicate *for that part*, likely should be re-open if an edit clarifies that problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I made a minimal reproducible example, see if there is anything need to be improved.

Comment: It looks like [mre] should be `object x = "bob";` and the question is how to use `x.GetType()` to get type of value stored in `x` (or if you want array `var x = new[] { new { B = (object)"aa" }};`) Since that feels offensive to me I guess you have some sort of actual misunderstanding of what you want to achieve... or most likely I read want you want wrong.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I am not sure if you can reach the picture from the link I posted. What bothers me is I am trying to get the type "string" while I got "object" from anonymous type's property.PropertyType( ). Let me make it more clear.

Comment: `r.Field<object>()` returns `object` (because the generic type is the return type of the `Field` method, so the property is typed as `object`. Use `r.Field<string>()` instead and the `PropertyType` will be the type you expected. The purpose of the `Field<T>` method is to get a value of the specified type, so specifying `<object>` defeats that purpose.

Comment: @madreflection Thanks for the reply. Rather than specifying type for every Field every time, I would like to make a for loop and let the program find the type behind the type by itself. In this case, find the "string" behind the "object". Declaring type is somewhat bothering, lol.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
I don't use anonymous types much, so it just dawned on me that you should be able to do something like:

```
data[0].BatchNo.GetType();
```

VS2022 worked out the named reference for me.

---

I'm assuming your array creation code is something like:

```
var anonArray = new[] 
{ 
   new 
   { 
      BatchNo = "someString",
      BatchSerial = 1234567890,
      etc...
   },
   etc...
};
```

Even then, not sure this changes the answer, but your code doesn't actually get the *type* of the property, it just gets the PropertyInfo for that property. You need one more line:

```
var declaringType = prop.PropertyType;
```

To get the type for that property.